# JS variable, assigned with session attributes, is empty until page reload

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, session

I have a code that set session attribute in my servlet:

```
session.setAttribute("culturesJsonArray", CommonUtils.toJson(foundLanguage.getCultures()));
```

And js variable on jsp page that stores this variable

```
<script>let cultures = ${sessionScope.culturesJsonArray};</script>
```

On first page load a get empty array `[]` and after page reload i get an array filled with values from session attribute. Why it can happen?

Answer (score 0):

It was because AJAX call not refresh the DOM, so session attributes weren't visible on the page. I solved it by sending session attributes in response of servlet as next:

```
PrintWriter out = httpServletResponse.getWriter();
String page = PagesManager.getProperty("page.languageEditorCultures");
Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
attributes.put(
"cultures", CommonUtils.convertListOfObjectsToJson(foundLanguage.getCultures())
);
Response response = new Response(page, attributes);
String jsonResponse = CommonUtils.convertObjectToJson(response);
out.print(jsonResponse);
```

and creating my html elements using these attributes with JQuery.

(Response my custom class that have `pageName` and `attributes` fields)